# JQuery, not animating my background image when trying to refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm talking about this site here: [malcolmtanti.com](http://malcolmtanti.com)

I am using this function:

```
<script>
  var image = new Image();
  image.onload = function () {
    $('header').animate({opacity: 1}, 2000);
  }
  image.src = "./images/background.jpg";
</script>
```

to animate the `fade in` of my main background image and the title etc. It should fade in the header element in my css.

This is the CSS:

```
header{
  position: relative;
  background: url(../images/background.jpg)  no-repeat top center; 
  background-size: cover !important;
  -webkit-background-size: cover !important;
  /*height: 700*/ 
  top:50px;
  min-height:95%;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity:0;      
}
```

For some reason, the first time I access the site, the picture loads for me, but once I press refresh, the opacity of the header tag is remaining 0. How can this be?

Comment: It is working for me, try adding a debugger on your onload event and see if it comes inside when image is loaded?

Comment: Also try moving `image.src` above onload event

Comment: im using chrome and edge? Are you using a different browser @RehbanKhatri I'll try that too

Comment: @RehbanKhatri the debugger shows that the image is there. the jquery is simply not working on reload somehow

Comment: I am using chrome. I think youre doing it wrong. Use docuent.load and animate header. don't use image at all. That might solve the issue

Comment: the problem with that is, that I dont want to wait for the projects in the bottom section to load before it loads. I want it to load immediately once the image is loaded. So that i avoid the progressive loading of the large image

Comment: Got it. I would suggest another solution though. How about using `onload` attribute in your header element and call a Javascript function inside to animate the element?I'm positive it will work and solve issue. Let me know if this works. I'll add this as a answer

Comment: If not on header element, add it on your `img` element to load image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a problem with the browser caching the image so that when you refresh the page it doesn't fire the animation since the image is already preloaded.

Try loading the image with a unique id (like the current time) to prevent this.

```
<script>
  var image = $('<img/>');
  var srcText = './images/background.jpg?t=' + new Date().getTime();
  image.attr('src', srcText).load(function() {
    $(this).remove();
    $('header').animate({opacity: 1}, 2000);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: the problem with that is, that I dont want to wait for the projects in the bottom section to load before it loads. I want it to load immediately once the image is loaded. So that i avoid the progressive loading of the large image

Comment: That works perfectly! How does that work? is it because of the date/time parameters int the srcText var? It therefore would have to load a new image everytime i guess? Right?

Answer (score -1):

U have used the link from (link tag, script tag )the href = "http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" and src of the script like this. Don't use like this. copy the code of above link and place it in your folder and refer that local link..